# standalone assertion libraries?

Tags: javascript

I was nearly through porting YUI assertion modules to standalone libraries when the thought popped into mind that I should have perhaps asked on StackOverflow if this was necessary first.  However I finished the libs:

YUIPort: https://github.com/gso/YUIPort

But thought I would duly ask as well.  Are there any good quality standalone libraries of assert functions - these can be very useful, e.g., checking the validity of arguments passed to functions (can save a lot of time invoking the debugger).

Comment: how about QUnit? a unit testing lib, but supports these...I don't know much about testing, all right? just suggesting.

Comment: The libs linked to above are tested with QUnit - I was looking for a standalone library, without the baggage of a whole testing suite.  Something that could be attached to a webpage.  I think I decided http://chaijs.com/ was the grooviest of the testing suites.  Assert.js https://github.com/Jxck/assert is more what I am looking for - not sure why I didn't just use this.

Answer (score 28):

*As of May 7, 2012*

After some brief research, starting with the most minimalistic:

- [assert.js](https://github.com/Jxck/assert) - port of node assert functions
- [jShould](https://github.com/eliperelman/jShould) - QUnit extension
- [should.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/should.js) - node library
- [expect.js](https://github.com/LearnBoost/expect.js) - based on should.js, standalone
- [YUIPort](https://github.com/gso/YUIPort) - YUI libs but standalone
- [chai](https://github.com/logicalparadox/chai) - node and browser, plugins inc. for JQuery
- [expectThat](https://github.com/dmohl/expectThat) - CoffeeScript

I have to admit that I do tend to agree with [a commenter on DailyJS](http://dailyjs.com/2012/02/23/chai/#comment-447866439):

> I don't understand why everyone likes these wordy assertion libraries.

Although I'm not a CoffeeScript user, I do tend to gravitate towards the plain assert.js style syntax rather than all this chaining.

Features that these libraries are developing include:

- plugable with the major test suites (saves having to switch between two libraries when coding)
- coding server-side (node) and client-side without changing libraries
- integration into the main web frameworks (e.g. JQuery)

Some of the major test suites include:

- [JQuery's QUnit](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit)
- [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/)
- [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/)
- [js-test-driver](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/)
- [YUI Test](http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yuitest/)
- [Sinon.JS](http://sinonjs.org/)

The [major web frameworks](https://web.archive.org/web/20140518164841/http://javascriptlibraries.com/) often include their own test suites.

Logging wise, there is [a discussion on libraries available](https://web.archive.org/web/20150810100502/http://ajaxpatterns.org/Logging#Tool_Support). They don't, at a glance, seem to have caught up with server-side JS as of yet.

Comment: The standard for logging seems to be log4j which was developed by Apache and became popular: [log4javascript](http://log4javascript.org/) - based on log4j, 
[log4js](http://log4js.berlios.de/) - API very simialar to log4j, 
[JavaScript Debug](http://benalman.com/projects/javascript-debug-console-log/) - plain wrapper for console.log.

Comment: [console.log-wrapper](https://github.com/cpatik/console.log-wrapper) - console.log wrapper

Comment: should.js is a nice library.

Answer (score 25):

```
function assert(condition, message) {
    if (!condition) throw new Error(message)
}
```

Comment: OP was looking for a library with custom use cases, not a custom solution.