# What a .js library has Asserts like "URL loads within X mSeconds"? or "response from server within Y mSeconds"?

Tags: javascript, assert

I find that with our new Web App we need to have some testing built in in case a page or resource fails to load.  (On slower tablets (I'm looking at you Kindle Fire) on a slow, high latency connection)  we get some failures of pages to load.

Ideal solution is to fix this and we're working on this.
BUT it seems that it's always possible (including having inet fail for a few minutes) and I'd rather "trap" the error with something like:

Assert.URLLoads (url, TimeAllowedMs, UserMessage)

I know there are [lots of Assert  libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472152/standalone-assertion-libraries/10480546#10480546), but I'm not familiar with any of them and wanted to ask for direction on which one to look at first.

We are using jQuery and our target browsers are Chrome and Safari (6.0 or higher)